# Git to svn: Adding commit date to log messages

Tags: svn, git, date, git-svn, message

How should I do to have the author (or committer) name/date added to the log 
message when "dcommitting" to svn?

For example, if the log message in Git is:

```
This is a nice modif
```

I'd like to have the message in svn be something like:

```
This is a nice modif
-----
Author: John Doo <John.Doo@company.com>  2010-06-10 12:38:22
Committer: Nice Guy <nguy@acme.org>  2010-06-10 14:05:42
```

(Note that I'm mainly interested in the date, since I already mapped svn users in .svn-authors)

Any simple way? Hook needed? Other suggestion?
(See also: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/148861)

Answer (score 3):

One way to accomplish this is by using a script, the `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable and the `dcommit` `--edit` option.

Save the following to a file, let's call it `svnmessage.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
c=`git rev-parse HEAD`
t=`git cat-file -t $c`
m=`cat "$1"`
if [ "commit" = "$t" ]; then
    o=`git cat-file $t $c`
    o_a=`echo "$o" | grep '^author '`
    o_c=`echo "$o" | grep '^committer '`
    author=`echo "$o_a" | sed -e 's/^author \(.*>\).*$/\1/'`
    authorts=`echo "$o_a" | sed -e 's/^author .*> \([0-9]\+\) .*$/\1/'`
    authordt=`date -d @$authorts +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z"`
    committer=`echo "$o_c" | sed -e 's/^committer \(.*>\).*$/\1/'`
    committerts=`echo "$o_c" | sed -e 's/^committer .*> \([0-9]\+\) .*$/\1/'`
    committerdt=`date -d @$committerts +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z"`
    m="$m
-----
Author: $author $authordt
Committer: $committer $committerdt"
fi
echo "$m" > "$1"
```

Make sure the script is executable: `chmod +x svnmessage.sh`. And run your `dcommit` like:

```
GIT_EDITOR="/path/to/script/svnmessage.sh" git svn dcommit --edit
```

The `--edit` option will `edit the commit message before committing to SVN` using the `GIT_EDITOR` environment variable for processing the commit message. See [`git-svn`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-svn.html) and [`git-var`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-var.html) for further information.

You could create an alias to make things a bit easier:

```
git config --global alias.dcommit-edit '!GIT_EDITOR="$HOME/bin/svnmessage.sh" git svn dcommit --edit'
```

Then just use `git dcommit-edit`.

---

The script relies on how [`git-svn.perl`](https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/git-svn.perl) siphons the [`git cat-file`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-cat-file.html) output to create the SVN commit message. The same technique is used to extract the author and committer information. A simple commit might look like:

```
$ git cat-file commit 24aef4f
tree eba872d9caad7246406f310c926427cfc5e73c8d
parent 7dd9de9b5c68b9de1fc3b798edbab2e350ae6eac
author User <user@acme.com> 1321054806 -0500
committer User <user@acme.com> 1321054806 -0500

foo-27
```

The script will typically have `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` passed to it as a parameter; the contents of which will contain the Git commit message that will be used for the SVN commit message.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. That sounds awesome! However, I am running windows... Do you have an example for Windows, too? Additionally, will this change the GIT_EDITOR environment variable only for the current operation or will it be changed permanently for all further operations, too?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Sorry, I don't have Windows at my disposal; maybe someone with Windows could give this a try and provide feedback. Setting `GIT_EDITOR` (or any environment variable) with a command replaces `GIT_EDITOR` just for that command; it does not change it permanently.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think it shouldn't be too hard to write a little program that does the same as your script - at least if I understand it :) Could you please shortly explain what the script does in general and those sed commands in particular? A concrete example would be helpful

Comment: Updated answer with some info on what the script does. The [`sed 's' commands`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) perform regular expression substitutions to extract the relevant data.

Comment: Thanks! I wrote [a little C# program](https://github.com/dhilgarth/Tools/tree/master/GitSvnCommitMessageEnricher) that does the same job. One more question: Is it possible to only add this additional info to the SVN commit message and to not also change the GIT commit message, too?

Comment: Probably not. `git svn` relies on Git's commit messages to "stage" its work. Or if there is a way, further analysis of the Git source might help answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Is it just about changing log output format?

```
git log --pretty="format:%s %an %ae %cn %d"
git help log
```

Comment: Not quite.

It's about rewriting the log when you do "git svn dcommit".

Comment: I see. Sorry for misunderstanding, I have no experience with `git-svn`.